# Delphi DEC CalcFile Message

Tags: delphi, hash

I've just stared looking at the Delphi Encryption Compendium (I used GetIt to install v6.3 in Delphi 10.4.2)

Here is a simple procedure I have used to calc a File Hash

```
var
 HASH : THash_SHA3_384;
 s : rawbytestring;
begin
  try
    HASH := THash_SHA3_384.Create;
    HASH.Init;
    s := HASH.CalcFile(edFilename.Text,Tformat_HEX);
    EdHashedFile.Text := s;
    hash.Done;
  finally
    HASH.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The resulting hash agrees with various online resources that calc a SHA3_384.

However a message box is displayed when it's doing the calc.

**"Absorb: number of bits mod 8 <> 0 or squeezing active. Bits:0, Squeezing: True."**

Don't know if it's important ?
if it is what do I do about it ?
if it isn't how do I supress it ?

Many thanks

Comment: FWIW, that does look to me like somebody forgot to strip their debug statements out.

Comment: Agreed, send a bug report to the packager, they may have built it wrong. If it's not their mistake they can send it upstream to the module developer.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I've raised it with the packager.